# How to show that a certain graph always admits three different Hamilton paths?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,A)$ be a graph in which every pair of vertices $k_i , k_j \in V (i \neq j)$ is connected by some arrow $(i,j) \in A$. Let's call this graph a *tournament*. Furthermore, let this tournament be non-transitive. This means that if there are arrows $(i,j)$ and $(j,k)$, this implies that there is also an arrow $(i,k)$.

Question: How does one show that a non-transitive tournament always has at least three different Hamilton paths?

I can see this is true for some examples, but I can't figure out how to prove this statement.

Comment: You can use induction to prove this.

Comment: Is there some condition on the size of $V$ ?  Because unless I missed something, that doesn't seem to hold for $|V| = 3$ and $|V| = 4$.

Comment: It does hold for $|V|=3$. It is an oriented triangle. Just pick the starting vertex and go two steps and you get a hamiltonian path. You have three options for a starting point.